# Salesforce 1 problem while opening a record

Tags: salesforce1-app

I am facing issues while trying to open a record in salesforce 1 using the url https//:domain/one/one.app.  Using this url I am able to view different lists for each object and go to the list of records. When I open a specific record the page is keep loading and I can see the javascript error. Below is the screen shot for the js error for a record detail page. Is there any configuration missing or a salesforce bug?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have overridden the record page with a visualforce page. This is what is causing the issue. The visualforce page is conflicting with the security settings in the org. I encourage you to open up a case with Salesforce Support (and please post the case number here).

In the meantime, there are a couple workarounds

1 - Remove the visualforce override

2 - Change the clickjack settings in your organization to allow visualforce pages to be served from an iframe on a different domain.